# Hyperref and ulem commands cannot be combined

Tags: hyperref, ulem

Some `hyperref` commands do not mix well with `ulem` commands. Compiling this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\sout{\hypertarget{label}{text}}
\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \put@me@back 

l.7 \sout{\hypertarget{label}{text}}
```

Same applies if we replace `sout` with other ulem commands such as `uwave` or `xout`. Is there any solution to this problem? It is nice to use strike-through to symbolize deleted text (Latexdiff does this if the proper option is specified)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `ulem` has restrictions, what can be used inside the argument.
Thus `\hypertarget` cannot be used directly.

It can be protected via `\mbox`:

```
\sout{\mbox{\hypertarget{...}{...}}
```

Or a better solution, would be to switch `\sout` with `\hypertarget`:

```
\hypertarget{label}{\sout{text}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\sout{\mbox{\hypertarget{label}{text}}}
\hypertarget{label2}{\sout{text2}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great! What is the disadvantage of the `mbox` wrapping? In my particular use case, and given that latexdiff is the one wrapping differences with a custom command, using `\sout{\mbox` is the only possibility.

Comment: oh well I see that mbox-contained text might go over the page margins...life is hard ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very old question, but just seeing it now. A new version of ulem.sty (April 2020) will fix this problem.

The offending part of `\hypertarget` was `\penalty`, which caused `\sout` to close one box and start another, with the penalty between them. This causes `\hypertarget` to lose track of its local context. But the penalty used was 10000 (no break) so ulem can skip processing such penalties completely.